# How to remove a item from a list(ListField) by id in MongoEngine?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

structure：

`{title: 'test', comments: [{id:1, title: ''}, {id: 8, title: ''}]}`

i need remove the id=8 item, thanks.

Comment: Hi you can pull items from an array: https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/queryset.py See $pull: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull

Answer (score 2):

You need to use $pull operator here :

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull

```
db.collection.update({'title':'test'},{$pull : { 'comments' : { 'id' : 8 }});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one example of the pull operator, using flask_mongoengine and assuming the parent object class is called Blog, and the comments are EmbeddedDocuments within Blog.

```
Blog.objects(id=blog_id).update_one(pull__comments___id=comment_id)
```

Notice the triple underscore in comments id.  This is because if you want primary keys on Comments, you need to add one in your model declaration like this:

```
class Comment(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True, default=lambda: ObjectId())
    ...
```

The lamba function will generate your primary keys for you.