# MongoEngine - Pull a reference from a ListField, by id

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I would like to remove some references from a `ListField(ReferenceField)`, solely based on their value.

I store information about images in the following Model:

```
class ImageUrl(Document):
    src = UrlField()
    counter = IntField()
    deleted = BooleanField()
```

We store the `id`s of the images encountered on a page in an `EmbeddedDocument` called `Webpage`:

```
class Webpage(EmbeddedDocument):
    image_list = ListField(ReferenceField(ImageUrl))
    ...
```

Finally, the `Website` model is embedded into a `RawData` model:

```
class RawData(Document):
    ...
    webpage = EmbeddedDocumentField(Webpage)
```

I would like to remove references to `ImageUrl` records from `RawData` records, based some some of their attributes (eg: counter value exceeding 1), and then set the `deleted` attribute of these `ImageUrl` records to `True`.

I'm doing:

```
images = ImageUrl.objects((Q(deleted=False) & Q(counter__gt=1)).all()
for image in images:
    # all RadData records containing the image in their image list
    for rdata in RawData.objects(webpage__image_list__in=[image.id]:
        # remove image from the image_list
        RawData.objects(id=rdata.id).update_one(pull__webpage__image_list=image.id)
    # set 'deleted=True' on the ImageUrl record
    ImageUrl.objects(id=image.id).update_one(set__deleted=True)
```

The `pull` operation raises the following error:
`OperationError: Update failed [Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array]`.

As i understood it from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/#_S_pull or [How to remove a item from a list(ListField) by id in MongoEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846109/how-to-remove-a-item-from-a-listlistfield-by-id-in-mongoengine?rq=1), I need to specify the key of the the array from which I want to remove the value. However, in my case, I'd like to remove a value from a list... How should I do that?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way the positional operator works is it allows you to query for a value in a list and then do an action on the first instance of that value, usually an update.  `$pull` will remove all instances from the list and this is what you want.

In mongoengine with references you can just pass the instance object eg:

```
for rdata in RawData.objects(webpage__image_list=image):
    # remove image from the image_list
    rdata.update_one(pull__webpage__image_list=image)
```

I cleaned up code, removed the duplicate queries - as you already have `rdata` no need to refind that document!

`OperationError: Update failed [Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array]` This means that you are trying to pull data which requires an array and there is a document where `image_list` isn't actually an array.  This is probably caused because on disk you have a document where `image_list` is not actually a list.  If you put a try except block you can have a look at the document that fails to see if that is the case and if so it will need manually migrating.