# AttributeError: "Class" object has no attribute ''update_one"

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I have a problem with removing and updating with the update_one method. It seems like the method had not been implemented in mongoengine. My objective is to remove a Student field from the ListField. In the sample code,  my model shows the database schema and my view show the routes of my application. I would like an example of what's preventing me from accessing the method (update_one) from my StudentYear class. I don't know how to format stack overflow so sorry in advance.

ListField(ReferenceField('Student')). I have been getting the error AttributeError: 'SchoolYear' object has no attribute 'update_one' and I have been looking around for a solution that will fix the closest I have gotten to was these two links but when I try it myself it did not works.

[MongoEngine - Pull a reference from a ListField, by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684687/mongoengine-pull-a-reference-from-a-listfield-by-id)

https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock/issues/458

Page 25 on the following link show removing and adding with update_one method
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/mongoengine-odm/stable/mongoengine-odm.pdf

```
requiredfile.txt
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-MongoAlchemy==0.7.2
flask-mongoengine==0.9.5
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
mongoengine==0.16.3
mongomock==3.14.0
pymongo==3.7.2
sentinels==1.0.0
six==1.12.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.2.1
```

## MODEL

```
from mongoengine import *

from mongoengine.fields import *

class Student(Document):

    FirstName  = StringField(default='')
    LastName   = StringField(default='')
    listNumber = IntField(default=0)
class SchoolYear(Document):

    year = IntField(required=True,min_value=1871, max_value=2020)
    students = ListField(ReferenceField('Student', required=True, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE))
```

## VIEW

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request,Response

from models import  Student, SchoolYear

from bson import json_util

@app.route('/location/', methods=['POST'])

def remove_student():

    encodedString = request.get_json()
    FirstName = str(encodedString['FirstName'])
    LastName = str(encodedString['LastName'])
    year = int(encodedString['year'])
    students_year = SchoolYear.objects(year=year).get()
    for student in students_year.students:
        if(str(student['FirstName']) == FirstName and str(student['LastName']) == LastName):

            students_year.update_one(pull__students=student)
    return jsonify({'result': 10})
```

Comment: no one seems to work with reference in python mongo but javascript seem to have more information on how to do all of these methods.

Comment: So it work with an embeddedlist instead of a ListField(ReferenceField(Class)) but i still want to know how does it work with a ListField(ReferenceField(Class)) because i could do things with the data store in a next bucket.

Answer (score 3):

Both `update/update_one` are available on queryset's

```
SchoolYear.objects(year=year).update_one(pull__students=student)
```

But only `update` is available on Document instances, so you should simply use `.update` instead of `.update_one` like in:

```
students_year = SchoolYear.objects(year=year).get()
students_year.update(pull__students=student)
```